# Angular variable's default scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

```
body(ng-controller='bodyController')
 .div(ng-controller='divController')
   h1 {{someVar}}
```

In the above html(jade), to which scope does `someVar` attached? to $scope of `bodyController` or `divController`?

How do i ensure `someVar` is attached to `bodyController`? 
The following code will ensure it, right?

```
function bodyController($scope){
  $scope.someVar = null;
}
```

I am trying to use  variable from $scope of bodyController, in the html. I want to prevent the divController to declare the variable in its scope.

Comment: This will help you http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DTx23w4z6Kc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing as *ensuring* scope through variable declaration. This is a dynamic language. Things don't work that way.

But by framework design, in Angular, child controllers inherit their parent's scope just like directives.

So this

```
function bodyController($scope){
  $scope.foo = 'Foo';
}

function divController($scope){
  console.log($scope.foo);
}
```

works as expected.

I'd use [directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for what you are doing though.

Comment: 1. Arn'te directives strictly for DOM manipulations only? 2. I am trying to use  variable from $scope of bodyController, in the html. I want to prevent the divController to declare the variable in its scope.

Comment: By DOM manipulation you could also refer to replacing `<title-div-stuff></title-div-stuff>` with `<div class="title"><h1>{{someVar}}</h1></div>` loaded from an external or inline template :)